# creating pdftk watermark file from command line

Tags: watermark, macos-big-sur, pdftk

I need pdftk to watermark a pdf. I’m generating the content of the watermark programatically and write it out into a text file. Then I use cupsfilter to create the watermark pdf, and then pdftk to apply the generated watermark pdf onto an eBook pdf.

I understand that pdftk applies page by page watermark pdf onto eBook pdf.

If I create a 62 line text file, with 61 empty lines and watermark text on 62nd, then it gets applied properly at around 5/6 of the page height on every page of the eBook pdf.
I add one more empty line, the watermark text disappears. It does not end up on the next page, it is simply not there.

My ultimate goal is to have the watermark text at the bottom of the second page of the eBook

So I would need to create a 3 page pdf, having the first page empty, watermark text at the bottom of the second page and an third page again empty

I tried to insert page break using BBEdit into the text file, but I do not get the expected result.

does anybody have a hint how could I create the required text file which once printed out with cupsflter into a pdf will create the needed watermark pdf (first and third page empty and line or two of text at the bottom of the second page)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so first, the manual is not entirely clear about difference between stamp and multistamp, and background and multibackground - it explains that the watermark pdf will be applied page by page onto eBook pdf if the watermark pdf is a multipage pdf, and that if the watermark pdf has fewer pages than the eBook pdf, the last page of the watermark pdf will be applied to all surplus pages of the eBook, and this is correct, but only in case of multistamp/multibackground option. If you use stamp/background option then only the first page of the watermark pdf will be applied to all pages of the eBook pdf, this was the first to figure out.

So I created two txt files using echo, one empty (one space in it) and one with one line of watermark text. Than I used pdftk cat option to merge the empty pdf with the watermark pdf, so I got two page pdf having first page empty and second with the line of text. Than I merged this file once again with the empty pdf, and ended up with 3 pages pdf.

Then I applied this 3 page watermark pdf with multibackground option to the eBook and got what I wanted - first page no watermark, second page the line of text and third an all other pages with no watermark.